# Code Joomla Template with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to learn how I can build a Joomla template based on Twitter Bootstrap. I am quite familiar in building within Joomla 2.5 and I have written a template using HTML5, but just wanted to clarify a few questions for my understanding.

I have written my HTML/CSS based on a 960px width but not sure how I would change this to use the row/span classes within Bootstrap.

As Bootstrap is based on a 12 grid layout, would I build 2 blank `span` 2 classes at the start and at the end to have a layout of 8 grids within the middle?

Or am i going about this the wrong way?

In regards to the modules, I am quite familiar in how I can add this, but just wanted to familiarise myself with the layout first before adding in the rest of the data within the site.

My HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Joomla Layout</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"> 
        <header>
            <img src="imgs/logo.png">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
                </ul>       
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="banners"><img src="imgs/banner.jpg" width="100%"></div>
        <aside class="sidebar"><h2>My SideBar</h2></aside>
        <section class="content"><h2>This is my section1</h2></section>
        <section class="list"><h2>This is my section2</h2></section>
    </div>
        <footer>
            <h3>This is my footer</h3>
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
    * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    background:#FFF;
}

.container {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    height: 1020px;
    width:960px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}

header  {
    text-align:center;
    height:16.27450980392157%;
    width:100%;
}

nav {
    float:left;
    height:6.372549019607843%;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background:#fe6b01;
}

.banners {
    float:left;
    height:24.80392156862745%;
    width:100%;
    background:#01AEF0;
    text-align:center;
}

.sidebar {
    height:600px;
    width:32.29166666666667%;
    background:#ec8400;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

.content {
    height:300px;
    width:67.70833333333333%;
    background:#CCC;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
}

.list {
    height:300px;
    width:67.70833333333333%;
    background:#01AEEF;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
}

footer {
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    height:16.37254901960784%;
    width:100%;
    background:#efefef;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:-80px;
}

ul li {
    display:inline;
    text-align:left;
    margin:30px;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {

    .container {
    height:816px;
    width:768px;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    .container {
    height:653px
    width:615px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .container {
    height:510px;
    width:480px;
    }

    .sidebar {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    }

    .content {
    width:100%;
    float:right;
}

.list {
    width:100%;
    float:right;
}
```

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to load the Framework in with:

```
// Add JavaScript Frameworks
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
```

It is built using a 12grid format yes, so you would adjust the spans accordingly to the output you wanted. Your HTML at present has no bootstrap setup.

As a good example, look at the Joomla! Protostar Template this is by default a Bootstrap template.

It is located in:

/Joomla! root/templates/protostar/

And it will give you all the basics you need to get you going!

You might also find blank.vc very useful too!

Comment: XWS, thanks for your reply. really appreciate it. Will have a look at what you mentioned to get me started.